# What are the minimum requirements to run a full node?

Tags: iri-node

Which minimum requirements are needed to run a full node regarding to RAM, CPU and Disk?

Answer (score 2):

A node should have at least 8 GB RAM. It's better to have more, because the machine, operating system and other services need some memory for themselves. The Java Memory settings should therefore be set one or two GB below the RAM-Size for 8GB e.g. to -Xmx7G

The node shoud have 4 cores.

The node should have a SSD with around 40GB space. The mainnet DB has around 9GB today but is growing.